# Is it possible to solve $ \frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{iR}{L} = \frac{V_0\sin(\omega t)}{L} $ for $ i $ without guessing at a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently trying to solve the equation for the current in an RL circuit driven by a sinusoidal voltage. I am asking on the math stack exchange because my question is only regarding the solution to the differential equation.

The equation in question, I am trying to solve for $i$:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{iR}{L} = \frac{V_0\sin(\omega t)}{L} $$

I understand that you can guess at the solution being of the form $I_0\sin(\omega t + \phi)$ and then substituting in values to find the parameters of the guessed solution, but I am wondering if there is a way other than this.

Comment: Integrating factors should apply

Comment: @FShrike Thanks, I took a look at the wiki page for it and it does look like this may be solved with use of those.

Comment: You can use many methods. Another example is Laplace Transforms.